# How to disable Bold Text set by iOS Accessibility setting in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, disable, bold

I know I should not disable any of the text and bold settings set on the device but I have a reason for it. I have disabled the text size by setting the textScaleFactor to 1 on a global level. But this does nothing to avoid the user from setting the Bold Text option that also changes the size of the text. How do I override that function also so even if the user sets it on the device there is no effect on the app? I have tried setting the fontweitgh on the text item using a TextStyle but that does also not stop the Bolding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [Josiah Mendes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10490377/josiah-mendes), I found out my original answer had some unexpected issues. It is safer to update the `MediaQueryData` created by `MaterialApp`:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
    builder: (context, child) => MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(boldText: false),
          child: child!,
    ),
);
```

---

**Old Answer:**

After checking `Text` widget I found out that it's using `boldTextOverride` from `MediaQuery` to change font weight of default text style provided to it. So I guess you can override it by wrapping your `MeterialApp` inside of a `MediaQuery` and assigning false to `boldText` and set `useInheritedMediaQuery` on `MaterialApp` to `true` to prevent it from creating another `MediaQuery`. Something like this:

```
return MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window).copyWith(boldText: false),
  child: MaterialApp(
    useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found it after looking at the code, I just added where I set the SclaeFactor

Comment: @Amir_P I use this code but doesn't work from my side

Comment: @MohammedNabil Check it again. I've used `false` instead of `true` in my answer for `useInheritedMediaQuery`.

Comment: @Amir_P Sorry My Mistake.

Answer (score 9):

[Amir_P's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70061828/10871073) is good but, when testing it out, I found that it breaks switching between dark mode and light mode in system, as the Flutter app would only apply system brightness after killing and reopening the app on iOS rather than immediately while the app is open. Therefore, I think that rather than wrapping `MaterialApp` in a `MediaQuery`, the following should be done:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
    builder: (context, child) => MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(boldText: false),
          child: child!,
    ),
);
```

The `builder` property of the Material App is specifically for overriding things like this - see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/builder.html

Comment: This is the best answer, simple and works! The one from @Amir_P is causing weird MediaQuery.of(context).size.height problems!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Since mine is the accepted answer, I will fix it with your suggestion.